# Delphi, TEdit text as action trigger

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am using a `TEdit` to allow the user to enter a number, e.g. 10.

I convert the `TEdit.Text` to an integer and a calculation procedure is called.

In this calc procedure, a check was built-in to make sure no numbers below 10 are processed.

Currently I use the `OnChange` event. Suppose the user wants to change '10' into e.g.'50'. But as soon as the '10' is deleted or the '5' (to be followed by the 0) is typed, I trigger my warning that the minimum number is 10. I.e. the program won't wait until I have fully typed the 5 and 0.

I tried `OnEnter`, `OnClick`, `OnExit`, but I seem not to overcome this problem. The only solution is to add a separate button that will trigger the calculation with the new number. It works, but can I do without the button?

Comment: This is a classic problem. It's best not to be too invasive. Avoid showing a dialog if possible. They just hurt the user.  Use a red background in the edit control to indicate that it is invalid. Or perhaps change the output to be text that describes how the input is invalid.

Comment: OK Thanks. I understand that there is not a real solution to it. I considered building in a delay. I can use the hint options for this TEdit to tell the user what he can / can't do and leave out the messagebox (which indeed is causing the pain).

Comment: I would use a `TSpinEdit` instead of a `TEdit`.  A `TSpinEdit` is specifically designed for numeric input, whereas `TEdit` is for arbitrary text instead.

Comment: A spin is maybe fine on mobile but it's dire on desktop where you have a keyboard

Comment: @David, with keyboard you can either give the user freedom to enter (limited) input or prevent what is about to be entered which would bring only confusion. I'd be for a small icon inside or beside the control indicating that the input is wrong (kind od what you've suggested).

Comment: Limiting input invariably frustrates the user. Why does my keyboard not work any more??!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use a timer for a delayed check, e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // reset the timer
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  Timer1.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  // do your check here
end;
```

Setting the timer to 500 ms should be fine for most users.

And as David suggested in the comments to the question: Do **not** show an error dialog, use something less intrusive instead, e.g. an error message in a label near the edit or change the background color. And also: Do **not** prevent the focus to be moved away from that control and do **not** play a sound, that's also very annoying.

For our in house software we set the background of a control to yellow if there is an error and display the error message of the first such error in the status bar and also as a hint of the control. If you do that, you probably don't even need to have the delay.

Comment: There is one problem in your code. And that is that the timer will keep checking validity of Edit text all the time. To avoid this the timer should also be disabled after each validity check. You can easily do this because timer will be enabled again after the next text change.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your help. I tried the timer option, but could not get that to work. I now have this code, which works (almost - see below), but requires the used to always type a CR:

```
procedure Calculate;
begin
  // this is my calculation procedure
  ShowMessage('calculation running correctly'); 
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
N   : integer;
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin
    N := StrtoInt(Edit1.Text);
    if N<10 then ShowMessage('<10!') else
      if N>100 then ShowMessage('>100!') else Calculate;
  end;
end;
```

I used the ShowMessage() here only to see if the sample code worked. In the real program I have left that out, as you all suggested.
I also included the 'turn yellow on wrong entry' (thanks David). The only issue is that if the user runs this I get a beep from my computer. I can't see what went wrong.  But what is causing the beep?

Answer (score 0):

There is a alternative solution provided by Embarcadero:

https://blogs.embarcadero.com/validating-input-in-tedit-components/

which solves the problem as follows. First create a user-defined message like this:

```
    const
        { User-defined message }
        um_ValidateInput = wm_User + 100;
```

In your form, define then a validate procedure and a refocussing object:

```
  private
      Refocusing: TObject;
      { User-defined message handler }
      procedure ValidateInput(var M: TMessage); message um_ValidateInput;
  end;
```

Then implement the validate-, editenter- and editexit procedures:

```
     procedure TForm5.ValidateInput(var M: TMessage);
     var
     E : TEdit;
       begin
         { The following line is my validation.  I want to make sure }
         { the first character is a lower case alpha character.  Note }
         { the typecast of lParam to a TEdit. }
         E := TEdit(M.lParam);
         if not (E.Text[1] in ['a'..'z']) then begin
         Refocusing := E;                       { Avoid a loop     }
         ShowMessage('Bad input');              { Yell at the user }
         TEdit(E).SetFocus;                     { Set focus back   }
       end;
     end;

    procedure TForm5.EditExit(Sender: TObject);
      begin
        { Post a message to myself which indicates it's time to  }
        { validate the input.  Pass the TEdit instance (Self) as }
        { the message lParam. }
        if Refocusing = nil then
        PostMessage(Handle, um_ValidateInput, 0, longint(Sender));
      end;

    procedure TForm5.EditEnter(Sender: TObject);
      begin
        if Refocusing = Sender then
        Refocusing := nil;
      end;
```

This approach has worked nicely for me...